# Reduce the required number of reopen votes to reopen a meta question to 3 instead of 5

Tags: support, feature-request, meta, vote-to-reopen

- Current state: currently, the required number of reopen votes to reopen a question is 3 on the main site and 5 on meta.
- Proposal: reduce the required number of reopen votes to reopen a meta question to 3 instead of 5.
- Reason: very few people look at meta questions.

Comment: This seems like a sensible proposal

Answer (score 2):

Pros - Easier to reopen meta questions that have been closed. Likely to provoke more engagement on Meta if questions can be closed and opened more easily. As you say, there's relatively few active users on Meta, so getting a quorum of five is a very high barrier.

Cons - Many (all?) of the meta-questions that have been closed recently have been closed by a binding vote, so having a lower threshold of ordinary users wouldn't actually be that helpful. Might lead to bad questions being opened more easily.

In short, I can't see any *likely* downside and several probable upsides. **I vote we try it, see how it works for six months and then revisit it. If it's been a disaster, we can always reverse it.**